# Index multiple elements of a JavaScript array with an array of indices

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I want to get the second element of an array, I simply index it with 1:

```js
const arr = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
console.log(arr[1])
```

Outputs `3`

Is there a way to index multiple elements of an array with an array of indices? Something like this (which doesn't work):

```js
const arr = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
const indices = [1, 2, 4]
console.log(arr[indices])
```

Should output `[3, 5, 11]`

But actually outputs `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  You've made a 2nd array of indices you want, so just loop through them.

Even simpler is to use `map` to transform the values, or to use `filter` to narrow down the original array.  Both produce the same result here, it just depends on what you may need for whatever you are putting this into.

```js
const arr = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11];
const indices = [1, 2, 4];

console.log('map', indices.map(i => arr[i]))

console.log('filter', arr.filter((val, i) => indices.includes(i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use the `filter()` method on the array as well

I used `_` as the first parameter since it is not utilized

```js
const arr = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11];
const indices = [1, 2, 4];

const result = arr.filter((_, index) => indices.includes(index));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Seems pretty inefficient

Comment: no is not? and it's pretty much the same approach the guy above gave you as an option whose answers you accepted

Comment: The `map` mechanism is `O(n)`, while the `filter` mechanism is `O(m·n)`